# Create a path to a nested resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had to create a new controller action called Copy:

```
def Copy
    old_record = @deal.contract.find(params[:id])
    new_record = old_record.dup
    new_record.save
end
```

I need to access a `contract` that belongs a `deal`.

How should I create a `link_to` on view to redirect to an url like that `mydomain.com/deal/1/contract/2` ?

In this case I'd like to access the *contract* number 2 that belongs to *deal* 1.

How should configurate my routes file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup nested routes by using `resources` or its singular brother `resource`.

```
resources :deals do
  resources :contracts do
    member do
      post :copy
    end
  end
end
```

This would create a nested path such as `/deals/:deal_id/contracts/:id/copy`. Note that it is declared as POST since a get request should not create resources.

You can create paths and urls to nested resources like so:

```
path_to([@deal, @contract])
link_to(@contract.name, [@deal, @contract])
form_for([@deal, @contract])
redirect_to([@deal, @contract])
```

However you may want to start by reading up on when and how to use nesting:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- [Nesting resources - Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)
- [Almost Painless Nested Resources](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/almost-painless-nested-resources/)